# Codeigniter - MySQL variable wrong

Tags: php, mysql, string, codeigniter, activerecord

When I try to add a column in codeigniter, I add this column correctly but the value is not the value at the variable...

When I define:

```
<?php
$hwid = "123893944";
?>
```

The Hardware-ID in the Database: "2147483647"

I dont know why... Please help me!

Model:

```
<?php
class Prometheus_model extends CI_Model {

    var $tables = array(
        'bots' => 'bots',
        'users' => 'users'
    );

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function tablename($table = NULL) {
        if(! isset($table)) return FALSE;
        return $this->tables[$table];
    }

    public function insert($table, $data) {
        $this->db->insert($this->tablename($table),$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function num_rows($table, $where = NULL) {
        if(isset($where)){
        $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $q = $this->db->get($table);
        return $q->num_rows();
    }

}

?>
```

Controller:

```
public function add_bot()
{

    $bot_data = json_decode($this->input->post('bot_data'));

    if($this->prometheus_model->num_rows('bots', array('bot_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) == 0){

        $to_insert = array(  
           'bot_id' => NULL,
           'bot_add_date' => time(),
           'bot_last_update' => time(), 
           'bot_os' => $bot_data->{'bot_os'},
           'bot_architecture' => $bot_data->{'bot_architecture'},
           'bot_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
           'bot_port' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], 
           'bot_version' => $bot_data->{'bot_version'},
           'bot_name' => $bot_data->{'bot_name'},
           'bot_hw_id' => $bot_data->{'bot_hw_id'}
        );

        echo $to_insert['bot_hw_id']; //HERE IT IS CORRECT, BUT WRONG IN DATABASE! 
        $this->prometheus_model->insert('bots', $to_insert);  

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you are inserting this piece of data into the database.

Comment: I guess you mean adding a row, right?

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: I don't see where you use `$hwid` in your code.

Comment: The code seems fine. what is the datatype of the bot_hw_id in the database? 

Have you tried inserting a range of different bot_hw_id's? Are they always different?

Comment: What's the column definition / datatype in your database of the "bot_hw_id" column?

Comment: Is `123893944` the actual number you are trying to insert? Or is it just an example? If it's just an example, please post the actual number.

Comment: Please use `var_dump();`, use profiler to debug this issue `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` so you can see your `QUERIES:` and see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing "issue" that your ID is larger than your table can store see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html).

`INT -2147483648 - 2147483647`

To solve this please change your `bot_hw_id` structure to `unsigned` that gives you even more "range" (in a positive values only), since IDs arent negative so often.

(Or change it to `BIGINT`)

Comment: But the number he is trying to insert is smaller than that... `(-2147483648 < 123893944 < 2147483647) == true`, right?

Comment: He is inserting too big number thats why he is getting the largest possible value (2147483647), if he changes it to either `string` / `BIGINT`, he will be able to debug this issue.

Comment: I see your point, but in the question he mentions `123893944`.

Comment: I also advise him to use profiler (in comments below the question) in there he will see in section QUERIES what he is actually inserting. I bet its gonna be some mini mistake in code that is causing this problem.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is now solved.

Comment: @Polymorphin, what did you do to solve it??

Comment: Doesn't make sense. First comment under my answer is so true that I can not belive that in a first place it was giving you troubles (having `int signed`).